# How to interpret the fact that the Fourier transform of $e^{-x} \operatorname{sinc}(x)$ is a constant - and what, if any, is its significance?

Tags: fourier-transform, intuition, trigonometric-integrals

Recently, I was fiddling around with computing Fourier transforms of different functions. At a certain point, I [found](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fourier+transform+sinc%28x%29*exp%28-x%29) out that $$\mathcal{F}_{x} [ \operatorname{sinc}(x)e^{-x} ] (t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \operatorname{sinc}(x)e^{-x}e^{-2 \pi i t x} dx = \pi . \tag{*}$$ It is therefore a constant value for all $t$.

I have two **questions** about this:

1. How can one interpret this fact? Is there some sort of mathematical or physical reasoning behind this that allows for an intuitive understanding of $(*)$ ?
2. Does $(*)$ bear any significance in mathematics, and if so, how and why?

---

**Edit**: it seems WA makes an error with the computation or calculates something differently. Either way, the results obtained above are probably wrong. I wonder what Wolfram computes in this case, and what the problem is.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $e^{-i2 \pi t x}$ or did you rather compute a variant of the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform)?

Comment: Ah no you're right, it should be the first option you mentioned

Comment: The result given by WolframAlpha cannot be correct. Only multiples of the Dirac delta distribution give constant Fourier transforms. I think that the Fourier transform of $\operatorname{sinc}(x)e^{-x}$ is not even defined.

Comment: @md2perpe are you sure? Could you substantiate that assertion somehow?

Comment: To check if the equation is correct you could try to evaluate the integral $t=0, 1, 2,...$ until you find a contradiction.

Comment: On the first part, that the result cannot be correct, I'm close to 100% certain. The (inverse) Fourier transform of a constant function is a Dirac delta.

Comment: On the second part, whether it is defined, I'm not as certain, but still quite certain. The exponential grows quite fast when $x\to-\infty$ so the integral is hardly defined. But not even as a distribution the Fourier transform of $e^{-x}$ (or $e^x$) is defined. The multiplication with $\operatorname{sinc}(x)$ doesn't help much.

Comment: @md2perpe seems indeed that the integral doesn't converge when $t=1$, for example. I wonder then what Wolfram computes and why it goes wrong